# How to disable font registration installscript MSI projects in installshield?

Tags: installshield

I have a Installscript MSI project, and I want to disable Global Font Registration inside Install Shield. How can I do this ?

I just have some font files that i copy them to Hard disk where i setup my application but it creates a key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.
I dont want it to happen.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways as far as I've found.

If you have a paid version of InstallShield you can use this method:
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/LangrefDisable00000677.htm

Or, if your application loads font dynamically (like we do, with QT), just rename your font file(s) to .font or something else and then readd them to your setup project. InstallShield won't recognize them as a font and therefore won't register the files.

If you really need them to have the .ttf extension, I would suggest you set a custom action (a .js script for instance) that renames the font file(s) after installation to ttf.

I hope this helps

Cheers